Excel VBA prints incorrectly
Excel 2019 for Mac.
NOTE: I have looked at this similar question and IT DOES NOT SOLVE my problem: Choosing paper size (NOT DEFAULT sizes) in excel vba
Excel 2019 for Mac does not have an Options button under Page Setup, therefore the proposed solution does not work in my case.
I have an Excel file consisting of 2 sheets and I would like to print Sheet2 with a macro. The macro is up and running, but it does not produce the same result as when manually printing through print preview.
The printer is Polono PL60, paper size 100x150mm, landscape orientation.
The printer has been set as the default printer in system settings and its paper has been set to 100x150mm as well.
When manually printing, I can choose the paper size to be 100x150mm and the output comes out perfect. However, I cannot set this paper size in VBA. The closest is Japanese Postcard, which is 148x100mm and works perfect in portrait, but not in landscape for some reason.
Here is the Excel macro that I wrote:
Sub PrintSheet2WithCustomPageSetup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Set the worksheet to Sheet2
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet2 not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Activate the workbook and sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    ws.Activate

    'Apply custom page setup
    With ws.PageSetup
        'Paper size: Use printer-defined "Polono" paper size for 100x150mm
        .Orientation = xlLandscape '
        .Zoom = False ' Enable Scale to Fit
        .FitToPagesWide = 1 ' Fit to 1 page wide
        .FitToPagesTall = 1 ' Fit to 1 page tall

        ' Margins (in centimeters)
        .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.3)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)
        .FooterMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.1)

        ' Center the content
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
    End With

    ' Print using the default printer
    ' MsgBox "Printing using the default printer with custom page setup."
    ws.PrintOut Copies:=1

    ' MsgBox "Sheet2 printed successfully!"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Playing around with the margins or the horizontal/vertical alignment has no effect.
Like I said, if I change the orientation to xlPortrait and add a .PaperSize = xlJapanesePostcard, it works great in portrait. However, this does not work in landscape.
I have tried print presets, last used settings, default settings, etc., but the result is always the same. Printing manually many times over with last used settings or similar, yields perfect results, but only works manually. Whenever I run the macro, it somehow goes to some default settings and messes up the print. Upon checking print preview after running the macro however, the settings seem untouched and I can print manually using the right setting without having to manually select them.
I have also consulted ChatGPT numerous times on this and have found no feasible solution. The printing absolutely needs to happen through VBA, as it is part of a much larger automatic process.
Does anyone have a clue how I can somehow override Excel's default print settings?

Have you tried setting the page setup on the worksheet directly, instead of via VBA?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939513/choosing-paper-size-not-default-sizes-in-excel-vba

@TimWilliams I have tried setting the page setup on the worksheet directly, but it got me nowhere, as the available paper sizes to choose from in page setup do not match the paper size that I need. They are all too big and far from the 100x150mm that I am using. If my paper size was available in page setup, then I would also be able to use it in my VBA. I have found no difference between the options available in page setup manually, and those available inn VBA.

@Michal I had a look at that exact question before posting but, unfortunately, it did not solve my issue. There are two issues with that question. First, they suggest "Under Page Setup, click the Options button. This will bring up the printer properties dialog box. Change your paper size to a custom size using this dialog box and click OK." I do not have an Options button anywhere, therefore I cannot create a custom paper size. Second, "Then in Excel run this: MsgBox PageSetup.PaperSize". This line of code does not work, so I would not see the constant value assigned anyways. Any suggestions?
